# Getting error to read edf file using mne-python

Tags: python-3.x, european-data-format, mne-python

I am trying to visualize the EEG data fie which is in `.edf` file format.For this purpose I am using MNE python.
here is my code

```
import mne
file = "/home/test.edf"
data = mne.io.read_raw_edf(file,preload=True)
```

Whenever I run this code below error massage is showing

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)
```

I could not figure out where is my wrong.

Comment: 1) could you provide a sample file?

Comment: 2) have you tried loading the file with `pyedflib`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to use use the file by specifying the path, event if you add a "~", the directory won't be identified. Better you try to be in the exact directory and try reading the file, i.e go to your home directory and then try specifying the file.

```
import mne
file = "test.edf"
data = mne.io.read_raw_edf(file)
```